# Manifold and Structural

Tags: java, extension-methods

I am not sure this is the correct place to ask this but I am experimenting little bit with [manifold project](http://manifold.systems/) and I am not sure that the scenario that I try to achieve is doable with manifold or not?

I have a class like following (which will be created from a third party software that I have no control over it)..

```
public ClassA {
    String getUuid();
}
```

Now I want that this class implements following Interface...

```
@Structural
public Interface InterfaceA {
    String getUuid();
}
```

for the following Scenario...

```
public ClassB<GenTypeA extends InterfaceA> {
}
```

but off course when I try to the following...

```
ClassB varB = new ClassB<ClassA>();
```

Java start complaining ClassA is not implementing InterfaceA.

Is what I am trying to do is doable at all?

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now achieve this in Manifold.  There was an issue preventing this from working: https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/issues/35, which was recently fixed. Available in release 0.38-alpha.

One other important note.  To complete your example, you must also provide an extension for `ClassA` to declare that it nominally supports `InterfaceA`, this is necessary only to avoid having to cast generic types involving `InterfaceA`:

```
package my_project.extensions.path.to.ClassA;

import manifold.ext.api.Extension;

@Extension
public abstract class MyClassAExtension implements InterfaceA {
}
```

Learn more: http://manifold.systems/docs.html#extension-interfaces

Answer (score 2):

This is called [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

```
// Immutable, cannot be changed
public final class ClassA {

    String getUuid() {
        return null;
    }
}

public interface InterfaceA {

    String getUuid();
}

public class ClassB implements InterfaceA {

    private final ClassA delegate;

    public ClassB(ClassA delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUuid() {
        return delegate.getUuid();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would call it the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). An Adapter wraps a class to convert its functionality to another interface, while a Decorator wraps a class to add behavior to it.

Comment: Probably. They're pretty similar.

Comment: Our number of Domain Objects are huge, I don't want to create that number of delegates manually that was the reason I was looking to Manifold framework.